# Use NumberFormatException with boolean variable

Tags: java

Is there a way to throw the error message if the user input is blank? I can't use catch (NumberFormatException e) because of the boolean variable.

```
 boolean numberSet;
 do {       
    numberSet = jerseys[position].setNumber(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of jersey")));         
    if (!numberSet) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number cannot be less than 0.");
    }
 } while (!numberSet);
```

setNumber method

```
   public boolean setNumber(int number) {
      if (number >= 0) {
         this.number = number;
         return true;
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }
   }
```

Comment: There are several good ways

Comment: Why would the boolean variable stop you? You should probably put a little more effert and detail into what the actual problem is, and what you've tried to fix it.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to set numberSet to -1 if I had the catch (NumberFormatException e) block.

Comment: Nevermind, solved it. Set numberSet to false instead of -1.